# scrollView linearlayout and listview

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I'm doing an android app, and I just want to have an scrollable layout, but inside of this layout I  want to put some textView and 2 listView, and this is my problem, the listView.

I need to include this 2 listview on the layout and this is obligatory need to be scrollable, and I googling and all I found is negative.

how can I put 2 listview on scrollView?? is not possible? and if its right what can i do? Which is the alternative that I have? I really desesperated because I spend all day!!

con someone say me an example of this?

really thanks!

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: Did you try putting a single listview first?

Comment: google strongly not recommend putting listview in scrollView and vice  versa.

Comment: Listviews are themselves scrollable and so don't work inside ScrollView. What exactly is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: do you have any sketch regarding your requirement?

Comment: hey thanks! 
I want to put all listview directly, without scrollbar, i want to print all my list.

the scroll is for all layout

if not possible using listview ehat I have to use?

Answer (score 2):

`ListViews` shouldn't be placed inside a `ScrollView` because the `ListView` class implements its own scrolling and it just doesn't receive gestures because they all get handled by the parent `ScrollView`. However you can add views you want to be scrolled to the `ListView` as headers or footers.