# Iniciolice layout on top position

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making a layout with a listView and other elements at the top, when i open this layout, the screen focus on the linearLayout, it's like the scroll it's set on the linearLayout, its there a way to set the scroll just to the top of the layout?

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
  layout= "@layout/tool_bar"
  android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
  android:layout_width= "match_parent"/>

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
     

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">        
     
    <TextView 
     android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
     android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
     android:text= "NOTIFICATIONS"
     android:textSize= "10dp"
     android:layout_margin= "10dp"
     
  />
 <View
    android:layout_widt = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height= "1dp"
    android:background= "@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    <RelativeLayout 
     android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
     android:layout_height= "wrap_content"  
     android:paddingRight= "12dp">
     <TextView
         android:id= "@+id/general_notifications"
      style= "@style/bold"    
      android:paddingLeft= "20dp"
      android:paddingTop= "20dp"
      android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
      android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
      android:text= "@string/Notifications"     
      android:layout_alignParentStart= "true"
      android:textColor= "@color/date_left"
      android:textSize= "18dp"/>     
     <TextView         
      style= "@style/light"    
      android:paddingStart= "20dp"
      android:paddingBottom= "20dp"
      android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
      android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
      android:text= "@string/global_notifications_text"     
      android:layout_below= "@+id/general_notifications"
      android:textColor= "@color/date_left"/>
     
  <Switch 
      android:id= "@+id/global_notification_switch"      
      android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
      android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd= "true"      
      android:padding= "18dp"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
    <View          
     android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
     android:layout_height= "1dp"
     android:background= "@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    
    <RelativeLayout 
     android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
     android:layout_height= "wrap_content"  
     android:paddingRight= "12dp"
     android:onClick= "selectWifi">
     <TextView
         android:id= "@+id/wi_fi"
      style= "@style/bold"    
      android:paddingStart= "20dp"
      android:paddingTop= "20dp"
      android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
      android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
      android:text= "@string/WiFi"     
      android:layout_alignParentStart= "true"
      android:textColor= "@color/date_left"
      android:textSize= "18dp"/>     
     <TextView         
         android:id= "@+id/wifi_name"
      style= "@style/light"    
      android:paddingTop= "20dp"
      android:paddingStart= "5dp"
      android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
      android:layout_height= "wrap_content"          
      android:layout_toEndOf= "@+id/wi_fi"
      android:layout_alignBaseline= "@+id/wi_fi"
      android:textColor= "@color/date_left"/>
     
     <TextView         
         android:id= "@+id/wifi_explaining_text"
      style= "@style/light"    
      android:paddingStart= "20dp"
      android:paddingBottom= "20dp"
      android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
      android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
      android:text= "@string/wifi_settings"     
      android:layout_below= "@+id/wi_fi"
      android:textColor= "@color/date_left"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
    <View          
     android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
     android:layout_height= "1dp"
     android:background= "@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    
     <RelativeLayout 
     android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
     android:layout_height= "wrap_content"  
     android:paddingRight= "12dp"
     android:onClick= "setTime">
     <TextView
         android:id= "@+id/notifications_hours"
      style= "@style/bold"    
      android:paddingStart= "20dp"
      android:paddingTop= "20dp"
      android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
      android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
      android:text= "@string/not_hours"     
      android:layout_alignParentStart= "true"
      android:textColor= "@color/date_left"
      android:textSize= "18dp"/>
     
     <TextView         
         android:id= "@+id/hours_data"
      style= "@style/light"    
      android:paddingTop= "20dp"
      android:paddingStart= "5dp"
      android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
      android:layout_height= "wrap_content"          
      android:layout_toEndOf= "@+id/notifications_hours"
      android:layout_alignBaseline= "@+id/notifications_hours"
      android:textColor= "@color/date_left"/>
     
     <TextView         
      style= "@style/light"    
      android:paddingStart= "20dp"
      android:paddingBottom= "20dp"
      android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
      android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
      android:text= "@string/not_hours_text"     
      android:layout_below= "@+id/notifications_hours"
      android:textColor= "@color/date_left"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
    <View          
     android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
     android:layout_height= "1dp"
     android:background= "@android:color/darker_gray"/>
     <TextView 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="APPS"
     android:textSize="10dp"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
 <View
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>  
     
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="305dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please share xml layout, first

Comment: sorry, its there now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scrollview (ListView) inside another scrollview (ScrollView).

[scrollView linearlayout and listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873880/scrollview-linearlayout-and-listview#answer-14874230) :

> ListViews shouldn't be placed inside a ScrollView because the ListView
>   class implements its own scrolling and it just doesn't receive
>   gestures because they all get handled by the parent ScrollView.
>   However you can add views you want to be scrolled to the ListView as
>   headers or footers.

Another thread talking about this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3496042/4559849